# Not able to interpret printf output

Tags: c

I wrote the following simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()  
{  
    int i;  
    i=1;  
    printf("%d %d %d",i,i++,++i);  
    return 0;  
}
```

The above program gave 3 2 3 as output which I am not able to interpret the output. I am using gcc-4.8.1

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior here!!

When there are multiple increments to the same variable in the printf() you can't predict the output.
The order of execution within the `printf()` is not defined.